# Php, separar palabras y guardar en variables?

Tags: php

Hola espero me puedan ayudar tratare de ser especifico: Lo que quiero es separar palabras almacenadas en una variable y guardarlas en variables individuales: ejemplo:

```
$cadena="Hola mundo";
```

lo que quiero es algo asi:

```
$palabra1="hola"; 
$palabra2="mundo";
```

Gracias cuento con ustedes... Nota! Mi cadena principal solo tiene 2 palabras.

Comment: y no te vale mejor con un array que contenga tus palabras? lo normal seria guardarlos en un array con un **$lista = explode(" ", $cadenaPrincipal);** ??

Comment: puedes hacer lo que te ha dicho el compañero, y con un bucle sacarlo en variables a parte si lo deseas. Pero para la próxima intenta poner algo de código que hayas intentado. He intentemos buscar un poco en internet antes de lanzarnos a preguntar, he buscado "separar palabras string php" en google, y me han salido mas de 8 links que explican como hacerlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si solo tienes dos palabras, puedes hacerlo fácilmente de esta manera:

```
<?php

    $cadena = 'Hola Mundo';

    list($palabra1, $palabra2) = explode(' ', $cadena);

    echo $palabra1 . '<br>';

    echo $palabra2 . '<br>';
```

Vamos por partes:

`explode` toma un elemento separador (en nuestro caso ' '), y lo utilizar para dividir una cadena y almacenar el resultado en un array. Como tenemos "Hola Mundo", esto generará un array con índices 0 => "Hola", 1 => "Mundo".

`list` es una construcción de lenguaje de php, toma índices de una array y los almacena en una lista de variables pasadas como argumentos. El primer elemento del array se almacena en la primera variable, y así sucesivamente.

Comment: Genial!! Esto de verdad funciono gg.... Muchas gracias

Comment: Usar `list` no me parece la solución idónea, por lo que dice [esta nota del Manual](http://php.net/manual/es/function.list.php): _En PHP 5, list() asigna los valores empezando desde el parámetro más a la derecha. En PHP 7, list() empieza desde el parámetro más a la izquierda... Si se emplean arrays con índices, normalmente se espera que el orden de los índices sea el mismo que el escrito en list(), de izquierda a derecha, no siendo este el caso en PHP 5...  Se aconseja evitar depender de un orden específico de operación debido a que este podría cambiar de nuevo en el futuro_ `explode` bastaría

Comment: @A.Cedano _Si se emplean variables simples, esto no debería ser un problema_ Cosa que parece el caso. No obstante, eres libre de plantear una solución más idónea... Todos estamos aquí para aprender.

Comment: Entendido. Aunque la verdad me pareció _rara_ tu respuesta... será que estoy acostumbrado a usar `explode`. Si son siempre dos palabras no habrá problema, pero si se tratase de más palabras, con cantidad variable, habría que almacenar todo en un array y luego obtener las palabras por separado iterando sobre ese array.

Comment: @A.Cedano, OP lo deja claro _Nota! Mi cadena principal solo tiene 2 palabras._

Answer (score 1):

Usa la funcion explode que te almacena las palabras en un array

```
$arrayPalabras = explode(" ",$cadena);
```

[API](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) de la funcion explode de php